# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the x-axis simply connected?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So in an Exam Question I found on the Internet, i saw that $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the x-axis is simply connected. But in my opinion, this shouldn't even be connected and thus not simply connected. I think of it as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ which is also not connected. So why should $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the x-axis be connected?

Comment: Not everything on the internet is true....

Comment: Are you sure this is what the exam question says? Maybe not the entire $x$-axis is removed but only $\{(x,0):x\in[0,\infty)\}$.

Comment: Maybe it was $\Bbb R^2$ less the positive $x$ axis.  In that case it is simply connected.

Comment: it's an solution to an exam, so i was very confused. The link is the following: https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/other/analysis2_mavt_matl/mlserie7-fs13 but it's in german, but still it really says what I wrote. So I can be happy that I was right i guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition given in the exam (the link to which you provided in the comments) says that a set is simply connected if and only if every loop is homotopic to a constant path ("Ein Bereich $D$ heißt einfach zusammenhängend, wenn sich jeder geschlossene Weg in $D$ stetig auf einen Punkt zusammenziehen lässt."). Well, this is indeed true for $\mathbb R^2$ without the $x$-axis.

This may not be the most common definition (since it does not demand connectedness), but since it's the one used in the exam, the statement is indeed true in that context.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there can be many definitions of simple connection: in this case it is clear that if you consider the definition that involves also the connection of the space, the property is false due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{y=0\}$ is not connected.

You can however define it by: every connected component is simply connected in the previous sense ($\pi_1=0$). In this case both connected components are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is simply connected, because it is homeotopically equivalent to a single point.

Answer (score 1):

A subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is simply connected if it is path connected and has trivial fundamental group.

Note that the set $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(x,y) : y=0 \}$ is not even path connected.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why i thought it can't be true, but still the exam said so. Thanks.